# 12V battery charger does not work

Tags: circuit-analysis, charger, proteus

I have an old car battery charger (12V 8A) that has a 3.5 DC volts on its output instead of 12V. Although i found a similar circuit but i could not understand how it works. I am guessing after the center tap transformer there should be two 14 V signals (gr1 , gr2) and a common signal named brown. gr1 and gr2 are connected to the cathode of the thyristors then anodes on the other hand goes to GND!

So i think the circuit works with negative half cycles instead of positive ones! and interestingly there is no capacitor for smoothing the waves. The brown signal propagated through the circuit and act as a positive signal.I sketched the circuit in proteus to trace the input to every circuit nodes:
[image: Proteus]

The RED, YELLOW and GREEN indicate charging, emergency and fully charged states, respectively. G1 and G2 are the Gates of thrystors 1 and 2.

However it does not work. The 47u cap is placed to keep the relay connected. There is connection between gr1 (or gr2 does it make a difference?) and (-)plate of 47u capacitor, if we keep this connection the selected nodes will have voltages look like: [Corrupted voltage waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOT7u.png)

And by disconnecting this two (gr1 from (-) plate of 47u) the following wave will be gained: [smooth voltage waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erj0J.png)
However in either case the voltage amplitude is too low.

The charger output is between Brown connected to relay and NULL which h should be ~12 or 13 V.
Could you please guide me find the problem.
[the proteus project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sviWjv_4mPMkb5vOb1m5pSOepu0sgtwm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your schematic is bit of a mess and too small (low resolution) to see all the detail. Please provide a larger image. The circuit around the Zener looks wrong. Also can you include all the wires? This circuit will not work properly unless a 12V battery is connected.

Comment: Tip: turn off the grid before taking the screengrab. This will improve legibility.

Answer (score 1):

> there is no capacitor for smoothing the waves

That's fine for charging a lead-acid battery. The control circuitry runs off the battery between peaks of the mains waveform. Charging a completely flat battery would be interesting, though you shouldn't let a car battery get completely flat.

> And by disconnecting gr1 from (-) plate of 47u the following wave will be gained (smooth voltage waves plot): However in either case the amplitude is too low.

With that connection omitted the transformer output seems to be ~30 Vpp on both legs of the transformer. Allowing 1 V drop across the thyristor means there's 14 V to charge the battery, which seems reasonable. So you seem to have a problem with your control circuitry rather than your transformer.

> the anodes go to GND!

Unusual but fine. The thyristor gates need to be biased positive with respect to their cathodes to turn them on. The configuration used saves the need to have a secondary control circuit power supply at somewhat more than +14 V to turn on thyristors in the positive battery supply line.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's looking clearer now, though note Bruce Abbott's suggestions. I've removed the now irrelevant parts of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an old car battery charger (12V 8A) that has a 3.5 DC volts on
> its output instead of 12V.

In general the output voltage of a battery charger is not valid unless a battery is connected. Your voltage reading of 3.5 V indicates that no battery was connected (or it was a 'dead' battery).

For this circuit to work properly you need to connect a good 12 V battery. Perhaps you did and found it wasn't charging due to a fault in the charger. If so then to diagnose the fault you need to leave the battery connected.

Your schematic has a few errors and some questionable bits:-

- R41 should go to the Base of Q1, not the Emitter.
- R41 and R44 pass enough current to turn on Q1 even when Q2 is off. I suspect R44 is a much higher value than 5.6k (56k?).
- R46 and RV3 are monitoring the battery voltage, so the top of R46 should go to battery positive, I'm guessing point E(?) between D23 and the NO relay contact.
- The part number of Zener Diode D24 indicates 4.3 V, which seems too low for 'Vcc' if U1 really is a μA741. I suspect 'Vcc' actually connects to the other end of R54.

After correcting these errors I created a rough simulation in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html). Here's the schematic (note some parts are substitutes or simplifications, but should be close enough for this simulation):-

[image]

Without a battery connected the average output voltage was ~3 V. With the battery connected the voltage was of course equal to it, and the battery started charging.

> gr1 and gr2 are connected to the cathode of the thyristors then anodes
> on the other hand goes to GND!
>
> So i think the circuit works with negative half cycles instead of
> positive ones!

Whether a half cycle is 'positive' or 'negative' depends on the reference point. The SCRs are connected to the 'bottom end' of each transformer secondary winding, which is the negative end when the SCR is turned on. The SCR connects this end to ground, so the other end is positive and emits a 'positive' half cycle. When the SCR is turned off its Cathode 'floats' below or above ground depending on the half cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I just copied the PCB, and it looks like this unfortunately (it seems not well designed). I'll try different batteries as a load and double check the Zener. About the 56k resistor, i guessed that too but the third band is more red than orange.

Comment: If R44 is correct then perhaps R41 is wrong. You should check their values with a multimeter (with power off of course!). Zener is probably OK, but connection to Vcc is probably wrong. Once you have a correct schematic you will be able to probe different parts of the circuit to verify correct voltages etc.